# How does Amazon Test Drive/Pieceable Viewer work?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have recently discovered a web application which allows you to run iOS apps in the browser. Said application is [Pieceable Viewer](https://www.pieceable.com/).

I was curious about how it works and is able to do its job so I did a quick google search and found a rather short answer on Quora:

> It looks like they are running multiple instances of the iPhone
>   Simulator and piping it through VNC. They've also hooked (method
>   swizzled) a number of messages such as openURL: which would escape out
>   of the current application.

This was interesting, but I wonder if anyone could give a bit more info on how exactly they are able to have multiple instances of the iOS Simulator open and being able to pipe each one through VNC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the underlying technology of a web site, rather than a user question when using the site.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few similar applications, like [Amazon Test Drive](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000667581), and I think all use the same technique. As Amazon announced, Test Drive run your Android application in an EC2 virtual machines. So as Pieceable Viewer: they may, in the easiest way, create multiple VMs each run an iOS simulator. Output is forward to your browser, using VNC or any similar protocol.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, could you provide any more detail, like: How are they able to set up Virtual Machines on demand and then selectively pipe VNC to your browser?

Comment: @Joshua Pieceable's going (partially) open source so the mistery will be revealed. Though it's not hard to imagine how they might have done it.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik That's great news! :)